# Design Patterns for project migration with new database

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, migration

I am working on a project that is converting to use a new database and it uses factory Method of design pattern for the functionality of class. So what can be the best approach for design when migrating to the new Database but the functionality more or less remains the same

Comment: This is a very broad question and is not dependent on any specific language. Hence I have updated the tags.

Comment: Thank you. If you have any opinions on the question. @Rajesh

Comment: I went designing the application by using Abstract Factory Pattern Factory, and Programming to interface Pattern knowing the Source used we can easily switch between the Services used for both/many data source implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably if both legacy and new database are relational your best bet should be an [OR/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Depending on how your system has been architected, you might find big problems when migrating code to use an OR/M. Thus, queries and write operations should be implemented in [*repositories*](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) in order to make your code agnostic to the data store tech.

Comment: What I mean by design patterns is Object Oriented Design Pattern. We need to keep in mind that I am accommodating the old codes as well in the new system. So I was hoping I could write it in a best way that does not touch the old system can easily use new code. and fits a place in the new code to use the old code as well. @Mati https://stackoverflow.com/users/411632/mat%c3%adas-fidemraizer

Comment: @DiwasSubedi Right! And this is the point. You can abstract and encapsulate some *concerns* so you just need to replace hardcoded queries or concrete class instances with interfaces. That is, your code still works but it's agnostic to the interface implementation.